# React not closing dialog box

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Im using materialUI to click a menu item that then opens a dialog box(child component) however after the dialogbox opens it wont seem to close and wont update the data for `noticeModal`. There are not any errors being thrown and i belive it has to do with using `useEffect` to `setNoticeModal(props.open)` for the initial state. Ive tried removing the `useEffect()` and throwing `props.open` into the default `useDate()` for the `noticeModal` however upon doing that then my dialogbox wont open anymore at all. What am i over looking here?

**holidaySettings.js**

```
    ...  
    const [dialogOpen, setDialogOpen] = React.useState(false);  
    const handleDialogOpen = (dataElement) => {
      setDialogData(dataElement);
      setDialogOpen(true);
      setOpen(false);
    }

    ...
    <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={handleClose}>
       <MenuList autoFocusItem={open} id="menu-list-grow" onKeyDown={handleListKeyDown}>
          <MenuItem onClick={handleDialogOpen}>Add Holiday</MenuItem>
        </MenuList>
     </ClickAwayListener>

    ...

    <div className="card-body">
      <div className="row">
         <div className="text-left col-12">
            <Styles>
               <Table columns={columns} data={data} />
               <HolidayDialog open={dialogOpen} onClose={handleDialogClose} data={dialogData}/>
            </Styles>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
    ...
```

**holidayDialog.js**

```
const HolidayDialog = (props) => {
    const [noticeModal, setNoticeModal] = useState(false);
    const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(new Date());
    const [holidayData, setHolidayData] = useState(props.data);

    useEffect(() => {
        setNoticeModal(props.open)
    });

    const handleDateChange = (date) => {
        setSelectedDate(date);
    };

    const handleClose = () => {
        setNoticeModal(false);
        console.log(noticeModal);
    };

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        const { name, checked } = e.target;
        setHolidayData((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [name]: checked }));
      };

    const updateValues = (e) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setHolidayData((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [name]: value }));
    }
    return (
        <Dialog
            open={noticeModal}
            TransitionComponent={Transition}
            keepMounted
            onClose={handleClose}
            aria-labelledby="notice-modal-slide-title"
            aria-describedby="notice-modal-slide-description"
        >
            <DialogTitle id="customized-dialog-title" onClose={handleClose}>
                {holidayData.HolidayName ? holidayData.HolidayName : 'Create New Holiday'}
            </DialogTitle>
            <DialogContent dividers>
                <form noValidate autoComplete="off">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col">
                            <TextField required name="HolidayName" id="outlined-basic" label="Holiday Name" variant="outlined" onChange={updateValues} value={holidayData.HolidayName || ''}/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col">
                            <TextField id="outlined-basic" name="Branch" label="Branch" variant="outlined" onChange={updateValues} value={holidayData.Branch || 'ALL'}/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row mt-3">
                        <div className="col">
                        <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
                            <KeyboardDatePicker
                                disableToolbar
                                variant="inline"
                                format="MM/dd/yyyy"
                                margin="normal"
                                id="date-picker-inline"
                                label="Date picker inline"
                                value={selectedDate}
                                onChange={handleDateChange}
                                KeyboardButtonProps={{
                                    'aria-label': 'change date',
                                }}
                            />
                        </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col">
                            <TextField id="outlined-basic" name="Hours" label="Hours" variant="outlined" onChange={updateValues} value={holidayData.Hours || 'Closed'}/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row mt-3">
                        <div className="col d-flex flex-column">
                            <FormControlLabel
                                control={
                                <Checkbox
                                    checked={holidayData.Web || false}
                                    value={holidayData.Web}
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    name="Web"
                                    color="primary"
                                />
                                }
                                label="Show on Web?"
                            />
                            <FormControlLabel
                                control={
                                <Checkbox
                                    checked={holidayData.CoOp || false}
                                    value={holidayData.CoOp}
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    name="CoOp"
                                    color="primary"
                                />
                                }
                                label="CoOp Holiday?"
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="col d-flex flex-column">
                            <FormControlLabel
                                control={
                                <Checkbox
                                    checked={holidayData.Phone || false}
                                    value={holidayData.Phone}
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    name="Phone"
                                    color="primary"
                                />
                                }
                                label="Use in IVR?"
                            />
                            <FormControlLabel
                                control={
                                <Checkbox
                                    checked={holidayData.Active || true}
                                    value={holidayData.Active}
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    disabled 
                                    name="Active"
                                    color="primary"
                                />
                                }
                                label="Active"
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </DialogContent>
            <DialogActions>
                <Button autoFocus onClick={handleClose} color="default">
                    Cancel
                </Button>
                <Button autoFocus onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
                    Create Holiday
                </Button>
            </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
    )
}

export default HolidayDialog;
```

Comment: is console.log of handleClose logging on onclose event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try this?

I am assuming **props.onClose** is making **dialogOpen** to **false** on parent(**holidaySettings**)

```
 const handleClose = () => {
       props.onClose()
    };
```

If **props.onClose** is not making **dialogOpen** to **false** on parent(**holidaySettings**).You can add close attribute which sets **dialogOpen** to false.

```
     <HolidayDialog open={dialogOpen} close={()=>setDialogOpen(false);} onClose={handleDialogClose} data={dialogData}/>

      const handleClose = () => {
           props.close()
        };
```

And passing **props.open** to Dialog

```
<Dialog
  open={props.open}
/>
```

Comment: Where is `props.close()` coming from?

Comment: @Dipsesh I figured it out its on `props`

Answer (score 1):

You are not providing any dependency to `useEffect` so it runs on every re-render. In your useEffect you are toggling the modal and hence the issue.

```js
useEffect(() => {
        setNoticeModal(props.open) 
    });//<---- issue - missing dependency
```

Solution - pass dependency as `props.open`. This makes the useEffect to run only when props.open is changed.

```js
useEffect(() => {
        setNoticeModal(props.open) 
    }, [props.open]); //<----- props.open
```

Comment: This works for closing the dialog box! however it seems to present a new issue, upon close I now cannot open the dialog box again until i refresh the page?

Comment: This is because props.open is always true. Did you make it false after dialog was closed? I assume you only made 'noticeModal' false

Comment: @DipeshKC How would i go about making `props.open' false?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the useEffect, you are resetting the `noticeModal` value to `props.open` which i believe is true?

I believe what you are trying to do is set the initial value of noticeModal.
Try changing to the code below and remove the useEffect

```
const [noticeModal, setNoticeModal] = useState(props.open);
```

Comment: in my question i stated when i did this then the dialogbox wont even open